# Migrate Win7 -> Win10 profile with high-resolution choice of deployment

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, user-profiles, migration

Yes, this is another question about migrating a user profile from one computer to another (Windows 7 to Windows 10 in my particular case).

However - I'm not sure the user I'm migrating the profile for really wants all of the settings/info actually applied to the new profile. I need everything to be backed up and deployable on the new computer, but for me to be able to choose what exactly I actually want to deploy.

I don't need for this to be fully automated - I don't mind some manual work - but I am asking how to people usually achieve this (if it's at all common).

Note: Initially, both computers are available to me and may be on, and connected to the network, at the same time; later, only the new one will be available and whatever storage media I choose.

Answer (score 0):

There are third party tools to move profiles.  e.g. Forensit

https://www.forensit.com/downloads.html

We do not highly customize profiles, so we capture documents, email (including OST cache), favourites and like. Then we build the new computer and recover the above.

Perfect profiles are less common than profiles with some to numerous issues. So doing the above gives the user a new profile with no issues.